# GDAL - Heroku OSError: /opt/homebrew/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.dylib: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: gdal, heroku

I am trying to deploy a webapp that utilises GDAL libraries. I have followed the heroku documentation pertaining to GDAL and Heroku here and here. My buildpacks are:

```
=== vygrapp Buildpack URLs
1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-geo-buildpack.git
2. heroku-community/apt
3. heroku/python
```

When I deploy my app through heroku I get this traceback:

```
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/tmp/build_4575d756/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
remote:            main()
remote:          File "/tmp/build_4575d756/manage.py", line 18, in main
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute
remote:            django.setup()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
remote:            apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
remote:            app_config.import_models()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 300, in import_models
remote:            self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
remote:            from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
remote:            class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in __new__
remote:            new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
remote:            value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 207, in contribute_to_class
remote:            self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
remote:            return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
remote:            conn = self.create_connection(alias)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 204, in create_connection
remote:            backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
remote:            return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/base.py", line 6, in <module>
remote:            from .features import DatabaseFeatures
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/features.py", line 1, in <module>
remote:            from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.features import BaseSpatialFeatures
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/base/features.py", line 3, in <module>
remote:            from django.contrib.gis.db import models
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
remote:            import django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions  # NOQA
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/functions.py", line 3, in <module>
remote:            from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import BaseSpatialField, GeometryField
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 3, in <module>
remote:            from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
remote:            from .fields import (  # NOQA
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/fields.py", line 2, in <module>
remote:            from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALException
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
remote:            from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/datasource.py", line 40, in <module>
remote:            from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/driver.py", line 5, in <module>
remote:            from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/prototypes/ds.py", line 9, in <module>
remote:            from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py", line 53, in <module>
remote:            lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
remote:            self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
remote:        OSError: /opt/homebrew/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.dylib: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote: 
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote: 
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to vygrapp.
Further up the deployment logs it seems to suggest GDAL is installed:

remote: -----> Geo Packages (GDAL/GEOS/PROJ) app detected
remote: -----> Installing GDAL-2.4.0
remote: -----> Installing GEOS-3.7.2
remote: -----> Installing PROJ-5.2.0
[...]
remote:          Building wheel for GDAL (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for GDAL (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for GDAL: filename=GDAL-2.4.0-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl size=3556067 sha256=0d4572a90907fb1fc9ded7caf5dea8915fe7bb90a00af90729e0749e6c2363c5
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-cpgmk7j0/wheels/d2/33/ed/d3e3985670395e432ebb1d410ab8675e624d391865ebc0bcfd
remote:        Successfully built bs4 django-allauth django-bootstrap-modal-forms psycopg2 GDAL
remote:        Installing collected packages: pycparser, urllib3, idna, charset-normalizer, cffi, certifi, sqlparse, soupsieve, requests, PyJWT, oauthlib, defusedxml, cryptography, asgiref, whitenoise, requests-oauthlib, pytz, python3-openid, psycopg2-binary, psycopg2, Django, dj-database-url, beautifulsoup4, gunicorn, GDAL, djangorestframework, django-widget-tweaks, django-on-heroku, django-heroku, django-bootstrap-modal-forms, django-allauth, bs4
remote:        Successfully installed Django-4.0.1 GDAL-2.4.0 [...]
```

```
My requirements.txt

asgiref==3.4.1
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2021.10.8
cffi==1.15.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.10
cryptography==36.0.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==4.0.1
django-allauth==0.47.0
django-bootstrap-modal-forms==2.2.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-on-heroku==1.1.2
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.11
djangorestframework==3.13.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.3
oauthlib==3.1.1
psycopg2==2.9.3
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
pycparser==2.21
PyJWT==2.3.0
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2021.3
requests==2.27.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
soupsieve==2.3.1
sqlparse==0.4.2
urllib3==1.26.8
whitenoise==5.3.0
GDAL==2.4.0
```

I can't for the life of me figure this error out.

Comment: Im getting the same problem. homebrew is a mac package manager (There are some people who try and use it for linux, but thats a terrible move) So I'm thinking that something in python-gdal is hard linking to a mac dylib, which breaks it for everyone else.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70709904/django-with-gdal-throwing-error-when-deploying-on-heroku) is how I resolved the issue with using GDAL/geospatial database etc. with heroku in the end: 

Not sure it specifically answers your comment but maybe it will help?

Comment: I worked mine out in the end. Turns out I had a .env with some hardcoded GDAL and GEOS paths that had snuck its way into the git repo. Whoops! We really ought be not using "hidden by default" files for environment imho. Its not like putting a dot in front of it makes it more secure :/